# list comprenhension using two list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How can I create a list C based on two list A and B using list comprehension, where C list contains an item from A just when items in B is `TRUE`. My `for loop` implementation is here:

```
A = ["ID","population","median_age"]
B = [False False True]
C = []
for x in range(len(A)):
    if B[x] == True:
        C.append(A[x])
```

Comment: have list A and B same length?

Comment: Should the first C be 'B' and commas between the false?

Comment: @AnnAddicks Yeah, A and B have the same length, and sorry, I made some mistakes in my question, the first C is really B list, and commas between logic values in list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
C = [ A[x] for x in range(len(A)) if B[x] ]
```

Comment: Note that "== True" is *always* redundant.  B[x] is already either True or False.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Please remember to "accept" one of the answers, so your question resolves properly.

Comment: Of course, could you remember where I accept the answers? I forgot how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
C = [a for a, b in zip(A, B) if b]
```

Doing something like `for i in range(len(lst))` is rarely idiomatic in Python, as you'd usually prefer to do `for i, value in enumerate(lst)`. But in this case, using `zip` seems both safer and more idiomatic as it manages cases where `A` and `B` are of different lengths.